# Key declaration with the value from the existing key which is defined before in the same map initialization

Tags: dictionary, gradle, groovy, literals

I've got a global map in `build.gradle` (the config is written on Groovy).

I want to know whether it's possible to ask for *already existing keys* (probably, they doesn't exist yet, I understand) during the map declaration by the map literal way after those places where these keys have been declared.

```
ext.app = [
        versions: [k1:'v1', k2: 'v2'],
        dependencies: [d1:'dep1:$versions.k1', d2:'dep2:$versions.k2']
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^             ^^^^^^^^^^^
]
```

Just to say *"I define a new key with the value of the key which possibly may be in my map"*.

```
newKey: map(existingKey)
  |
  V
newKey: existingValue
```

Tried to clarify it simply. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy can't autoreference its maps. `with` will work fine, though:

```
app = [:].with {
    versions = [
        k1: 'v1', 
        k2: 'v2'
    ]
    dependencies = [
        d1:"dep1:$versions.k1",
        d2:"dep2:$versions.k2"
    ]
    it
}

assert app.dependencies.d1 == "dep1:v1"
assert app.dependencies.d2 == "dep2:v2"
```

In a `with` block, all method calls are delegated to the calling object, thus, a `$versions.k1` will be rerouted to the map being created.

Note the `it` at the end of the `with` block, otherwise the `app` variable won't contain the map, but instead will contain whatever that closure return.

Comment: thank you for the response. Not including these 2 maps, `ext.app` contains other composite maps, can I put more than 2 maps there?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko yes, you are free to declare how many maps you want, it is a block of code, these `versions = [:]` and `dependencies = [:]` are actually setting properties in the calling map.